# Как проверить аккаунты Vk на бан? VK API

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Отправляю такой запрос: `https://oauth.vk.com/token?username=login&password=pass&scope=offline,groups,photos,wall,notify,friends,audio,video,stories,pages,status,notes,messages,ads,docs,notifications,stats,email,market&client_id=3140623&client_secret=VeWdmVclDCtn6ihuP1nt&grant_type=password&v=5.92`

Но если аккаунт в бане или не верный пароль Вк просто не дает ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, вк не давал ответ потому что я не передал в запросе куки и юзер агента